# Magnetic NSWindows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frame, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I'm trying let two NSWindows to move together (NSWindows are Attached to each other). by using

`- (void)windowDidMove:(NSNotification *)notification`

But this method is lazy and it's not working live. Overriding `setFrameOrigin` and other `setFrame` methods did not work as well.
I was wondering what is the best way to do this?
I'll appreciate any suggestions with different approaches.

Comment: Check out the concept of child windows - that seems like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child Windows seem to be best suited for your situation.

They are simple enough to implement, and are done through the [`-addChildWindow:ordered:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIBCGJE) method of `NSWindow`. The reference explains it pretty well, so I'll just copy that here:

> After the childWindow is added as a child of the window, it is
>   maintained in relative position indicated by orderingMode for
>   subsequent ordering operations involving either window. While this
>   attachment is active, moving childWindow will not cause the window to
>   move (as in sliding a drawer in or out), but moving the window will
>   cause childWindow to move.

In essence, when you move the parent window, the child window will move with it without additional code. Sounds like what you want.